Firebase autogenerated keys usage in Node.js json
So I am creating a project using a Firebase database and React / Node.js to consult it.
I created a couple of entries via POST request like this:
const res = await fetch(`${MYFIREBASE}/posts.json`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(post)    
});

Then I consult these posts in another page like this:
const res = await fetch(`${MYFIREBASE}/posts.json`, { method: 'GET'});
const json = await res.json();
console.log(json)

And I get this result from it:
{
    '-O5NIwGpZU_GNQb75BPS': {
        post: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
        name: 'name1'
    },
    '-O5NK_uGPJySPQo-ZmDF': {
        post: [ [Object], [Object] ],
        name: 'name2'
    }
}

Now my problem is, and I've been looking all over Google and this site to no use, how can I access my data (that is behind the autogenerated key as a tag), in my code?
Since this is an object I need the key to access the value but the key is an autogenerated value that I of course can't know beforehand. I am feeling pretty lost with this.
I tried stupid things like json[0] and whatever I could think of, but it does not makes sense because that is not how objects properties are accessed. The only other solution I could think of is access the Object.keys(json) but it doesn't make any sense that I have to use a workaround for something as simple as consulting all the entries on a document.
I tried reading (to be fair scanning) the firebase docs but they were no use or I missed the relevant sections.

"The only other solution I could think of is access the Object.keys(json) but it doesn't make any sense that I have to use a workaround for something as simple as consulting all the entries on a document" I don't quite follow. This is a standard way to access all entries in an object. And if you don't know what the keys are, then you have to access all of them. There are also Object.values() or Object.entries() but are essentially the same "workaround" as Object.keys(). I'm not sure what solution you're looking for which isn't keys/values/entries.

Oh, i didn’t get that was the standard way. I’ve never used firebase before I was hoping o could just query and get an array or something idk, ty

If you don't want to use Object.keys (as VLAZ commented and the cosmic introvert dude answered), you can use a for in loop:
for (const key in json) {
  console.log(key, json[key]);
}

Both approaches are equally idiomatic and give you the exact same result, the for in loop just doesn't have to create a closure.

I really like this answer, idky but using Object.keys() always feels kinda hacky to me. This is exactly what I was looking for, I feel dumb now for not thinking about it, but I am kinda rusty.

Neither of these approaches is hacky, they're just different syntaxes to do the same.  --- This syntax has been in JavaScript since ES6, it just wasn't used that much until folks started needing await inside the loop's body.

Object.keys itself is the best solution for your case. This is the best way because you don't actually know the IDs of the documents you actually want to read.
So it's best to stick with something like this:
// Get all keys
const keys = Object.keys(json);

// Iterate over keys
keys.forEach(key => {
    console.log('Key:', key);
    console.log('Data for this key:', data[json]);
});

Hope this helps :)
